# Android Studio kotlin chat screen layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to build a chat layout. Everything is working fine. When users match each other, they can write messages and the messages appear in the chat screen. However, there is this giant gap in between my chat bubbles.

I read the official Android Chat Bubble documentation, went through YouTube videos and stack overflow. I don't really see where I am going wrong here. My bubbles appear in real time, I can read users chats when testing with two virtual android devices, however the chats have a giant gap in between them and are not on top of each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.ChatActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigationLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_height"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_margin"
    android:background="@color/shadow"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topPhotoIV"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_height"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/chat_margin"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topNameTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/navigation_height"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/chat_margin"/>

</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messagesRV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/messageET"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/navigationLayout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    style="@style/sendButton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/send_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/send_height"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_margin"
    android:onClick="onSend"
    android:text="@string/send_button_text"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageET"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/send_height_max"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/chat_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/chat_margin"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_box_bg_rounded"
    android:hint="@string/hint_message"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/send_height"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[chat screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhhJB.png)

[chatxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8rjE.png)

[currentUserMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVwIv.png)

[otherUserMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPanE.png)

I ended up changing the recycler view to wrap_content and it is still having a gap. I think I am missing somethinghere?

[StillAGap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS4Ef.png)

So I went into the item_current_user_message.xml and the item_other_user_message.xml and switched match_parent to wrap_content and voila, it works. :) Thank you!

[FIXEDchatBubbles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I2QI.png)

Comment: paste xml of the chat adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is because of the `match_parent` heigh to the `layout` of the chat adapter. Make sure the adapter's layout should have height as `wrap_content`. Setting height to `wrap_content` will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and answer. Do you know where exactly? Sorry, I am a little lost.

Comment: Wow! You are gold! I figured it out. You were right, it was the layout wrap_content on my item_other_user_message.xml and the item_current_user_message.xml

Comment: You are welcome. you can accept the answer if it was right